# I need a vertical accordion plus content slider script for jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I need a vertical accordion script that has a content space to the right of it.

For each option that is clicked the content space to the right of the is propagated with related content.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Is this what you'd like?](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion)

Hope it helps

Edit: 
Another three pretty good-looking accordions: "ABC, easy as 
[one1](http://www.madeincima.eu/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/), [two2](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_simple_horizontal_accordion.htm),
[seven7](http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/)"

(sorry but it's late and my mind is fried at this time of the day:) )

Comment: Close, I know how to do a straight vertical accordion like that, I'll probably just have to use one that has some callback features built in so that when someone clicks one accordion option is shows a div next to the accordion, and when they click the next it shows another...

Comment: well you can add your on-click events to the handle, and that works with any accordion implementation. eg: `$('.accordion-handle').click(/*your custom method to show a div*/);` and this would work with any accordion - at least i believe it would (didn't test it)

Comment: Thats what I figured I would do.  Going to jump in tomoorrow

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Wordpress Plugins option in the menu for the following site - http://www.designchemical.com/blog/. Not quite an accordion effect but the animation can easily be changed to suit